# Stray WM_SIZE causes resize to a wrong size

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a tough bug in which I get a misplaced `WM_SIZE` message that causes my window to resize to a wrong size.

Scenario 1 (good):

1. The user performs an oparation that enlarges the window (among other non-windowing operations).
2. The application calls SetWindowPlacement with the larger size.
3. The window resizes correctly.

Scenario 2 (bug):

1. Same as 1 and 2 above.
2. In the few seconds before  the window resizes, the user drags the window by its caption (it is possible to do so, since the operation takes a few seconds to complete).
3. The window resizes to the larger size, and then immediately shrinks to the original size.

Using Spy++, I see that there is indeed a `WM_SIZE` sent with the larger size, but at the end also an extra `WM_SIZE` with the previous size.

I tried following other relevant messages: `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` – none hinted on what was happening.

Any idea where I should look for the origin of this stray message?

Comment: *"it is possible to do so, since the operation takes a few seconds to complete"* - There's your bug, probably. An operation that presumably runs on the UI thread isn't supposed to take several seconds to complete. Offload it, and get your UI back to being responsive.

Comment: (OP) could very much be the case, worth looking into. However why would the extra WM_SIZE be sent?

Comment: We would be in a much better position to comment on that if we had a [mcve] to evaluate.

Comment: We are not yet clear what your specific implementation is, and I cannot reproduce your problem.